# javascript/jquesry find max value in tables and get row data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

i have problem with tables. PHP script dynamically creates about 20 tables. I want with JavaScript find max value by class, when collect table name (h4 tag) and all row data. When all row data put in other widget table above all tables (like top gainer widget in web). Any help pls? :)

```
<section id="tables">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
     <h4>Table 1</h4>
     <table>
       <tr>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Price</th>
         <th>Volume</th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Name1</td>
         <td class="up">20</td>
         <td>100</td>
       </tr>
     </table>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
     <h4>Table 2</h4>
     <table>
       <tr>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Price</th>
         <th>Volume</th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Name1</td>
         <td class="up">40</td>
         <td>60</td>
       </tr>
     </table>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you specify exactly the output you are looking for?

Comment: are you looking for the ascending and descending order?

Comment: @gurvinder372 output by example: TableName:, Name:, Price:, Volume:

Answer (score 0):

You can give some class to the parent div of the h4 tag table and then use the table tag as a child node and do the required operation.

```
<section id="tables">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 MyTableContainer">
     <h4>Table 1</h4>
     <table>
       <tr>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Price</th>
         <th>Volume</th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Name1</td>
         <td class="up">20</td>
         <td>100</td>
       </tr>
     </table>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12  MyTableContainer">
     <h4>Table 2</h4>
     <table>
       <tr>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Price</th>
         <th>Volume</th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Name1</td>
         <td class="up">40</td>
         <td>60</td>
       </tr>
     </table>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Then your script.

```
<script>
    //create a class
    function MyTableClass()
    {
        var TableName = "";
        var TableId = "";
        var Rows = [];//array of MyRowClass
    }

    function MyRowClass()
    {
        var Name = "";
        var Price = "";
        var Volume = "";
    }

    var TableContainers = document.getElementsByClassNam("MyTableContainer");

    for(var i = 0; i < TableContainers.length; ++i)
    {
         //loop through all the tables and store them in 
         //the variables of MyTableClass and MyRowClass and 
         //then find the max value out of them.
    }
</script>
```

I hope that helps.